# Symbol SDK: Waiting for transaction to complete throws UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs, blockchain

I am trying to work with [SymbolSdk](https://nemtech.github.io/index.html).

I try to get the balance of a list of accounts for a given "[mosaic](https://nemtech.github.io/concepts/mosaic.html)".

I want the code to query the blockchain and resolve promises when the balance has been properly read for every user.

Then I want to join all the promises and display the output of every query at the end.

I got a code sample from [symbol documentation](https://nemtech.github.io/guides/monitor/turning-the-asynchronous-transaction-announcement-into-synchronous.html) showing how to trigger code when the information is received from the blockchain.

However it keeps throwing `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` and I cannot find a way to catch these errors.

I guess they come from somewhere in `accountHttp.getAccountInfo(userAddress)` function, but I could not dive any further.

```js
import * as SymbolSdk from 'symbol-sdk';
import { merge, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const nodeUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

export async function userBalance(userAddress: SymbolSdk.Address, mosaicId: SymbolSdk.MosaicId): Promise<SymbolSdk.UInt64> {
    const repositoryFactory = new SymbolSdk.RepositoryFactoryHttp(nodeUrl);
    const accountHttp = repositoryFactory.createAccountRepository();
    return new Promise<SymbolSdk.UInt64>(async (resolve, reject) => {
        accountHttp.getAccountInfo(userAddress)
            .pipe(catchError((err) => { 
                const next = of(err)
                reject(err);
                return next;
            }))
            .subscribe((transactions) => {
                for (const mosaic of transactions.mosaics) {
                    // console.log(userAddress.plain(), mosaic.id.toHex(), mosaic.amount.toString());
                    if (mosaicId.equals(mosaic.id)) {
                        resolve(mosaic.amount);
                    }
                }
                resolve(new SymbolSdk.UInt64([0, 0]));
            },
            (err) => reject(err))
        });
}

if (require.main === module) {
    const promiseList = [];
    const users = ["TCC4A2H6VX4MVBYHBG33JRCL7SI4Z7OKSKUQRNXS", "TBHE2SZCMVGQTDDVSMM6G7KE33IWCXA726WXEV3H", "TBKFTBO4X5EIEHE4LDWVFALJGQU3HCVTAHN2NXCH",
    "TCWUJ4ENXWC4QYJ4N7ESVUHTBXL6IJ4TTPNFME3F", "TC2X5PCGSOEGX6TPZYTZQZYJBOP2QOPDC4VQ5GCK"];
    const rawMosaicId = "0874BB5FEAAA53C4";
    users.forEach(async (user) => {
        const promise = new Promise<[string, SymbolSdk.UInt64, SymbolSdk.MosaicId]>((resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                const address = SymbolSdk.Address.createFromRawAddress(user);
                const mosaicId = new SymbolSdk.MosaicId(rawMosaicId);
                userBalance(address, mosaicId).then((amount) => {
                    resolve([user, amount, mosaicId]);
                }).catch(reject);
            }
            catch (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
        });
        promiseList.push(promise);
    });
    Promise.allSettled(promiseList).then((values) => {
        console.log("Chain over");
        values.forEach((settled) => {
            if (settled.status === "fulfilled")
            {
                const [user, amount, mosaicId] = settled.value;
                console.log(`User ${user}, amount of ${mosaicId.toHex()}: ${amount.toString()}`);
            } else {
                console.log(`Failed to get balance, reason: ${settled.reason}`);
            }
        });
    }).catch(console.error);
}
```

Here is an example of the output I get:

```
(node:30500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: HttpError: HTTP request failed
    at Request._callback (/home/my_user/my_projects/my_symbol_project/node_modules/symbol-openapi-typescript-node-client/dist/api/nodeRoutesApi.js:168:40)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/my_user/my_projects/my_symbol_project/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/my_user/my_projects/my_symbol_project/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/my_user/my_projects/my_symbol_project/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1225:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:30500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:30500) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:30500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: HttpError: HTTP request failed
    at Request._callback (/home/my_user/my_projects/my_symbol_project/node_modules/symbol-openapi-typescript-node-client/dist/api/nodeRoutesApi.js:168:40)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/my_user/my_projects/my_symbol_project/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/my_user/my_projects/my_symbol_project/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/my_user/my_projects/my_symbol_project/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1225:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:30500) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
Chain over
User TCC4A2H6VX4MVBYHBG33JRCL7SI4Z7OKSKUQRNXS, amount of 0874BB5FEAAA53C4:  0
User TBHE2SZCMVGQTDDVSMM6G7KE33IWCXA726WXEV3H, amount of 0874BB5FEAAA53C4:  169489
User TBKFTBO4X5EIEHE4LDWVFALJGQU3HCVTAHN2NXCH, amount of 0874BB5FEAAA53C4:  177213
User TCWUJ4ENXWC4QYJ4N7ESVUHTBXL6IJ4TTPNFME3F, amount of 0874BB5FEAAA53C4:  180560
User TC2X5PCGSOEGX6TPZYTZQZYJBOP2QOPDC4VQ5GCK, amount of 0874BB5FEAAA53C4:  6472738
```

Answer (score 0):

> However it keeps throwing UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning and I
>   cannot find a way to catch these errors.

Here are the examples how to cause this error

```js
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", event => {
  console.warn(`UNHANDLED PROMISE REJECTION: ${event.reason}`);
});

(async _ => {
    throw new Error('from await/async');
})();

new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject('from promise'));
```

Looks quite trivial, isn't it?

However, It is difficult to spot any issues in your code.

I refactored it a bit and mocked values.

```js
window.module = true;
window.require = {
    main: true
}
window.SymbolSdk = {
    Address: {
        createFromRawAddress: () => ''
    }
}

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", event => {
    console.warn(`UNHANDLED PROMISE REJECTION: ${event.reason}`);
});

window.SymbolSdk.RepositoryFactoryHttp = function() {
        this.createAccountRepository = () => {
            return {
                getAccountInfo: () => Math.random() > 0.5 ? rxjs.throwError('test') : rxjs.of({
                    mosaics: [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            amount: 10
                        }
                    ]
                })
            }
        }
    },

window.SymbolSdk.MosaicId = function() {
    this.equals = function() {
        return true;
    }
    this.toHex = function() {
        return ''
    }
}

window.SymbolSdk.UInt64 = function() {

}

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", event => {
  console.warn(`UNHANDLED PROMISE REJECTION: ${event.reason}`);
});

if (require.main === module) {
    (async _ => {
    const promiseList = [];
    const userIds = ["TCC4A2H6VX4MVBYHBG33JRCL7SI4Z7OKSKUQRNXS", "TBHE2SZCMVGQTDDVSMM6G7KE33IWCXA726WXEV3H", "TBKFTBO4X5EIEHE4LDWVFALJGQU3HCVTAHN2NXCH",
    "TCWUJ4ENXWC4QYJ4N7ESVUHTBXL6IJ4TTPNFME3F", "TC2X5PCGSOEGX6TPZYTZQZYJBOP2QOPDC4VQ5GCK"];
    const rawMosaicId = "0874BB5FEAAA53C4";
    
    const users = userIds.map(async (userId) => {
        const address = SymbolSdk.Address.createFromRawAddress(userId);
        const mosaicId = new SymbolSdk.MosaicId(rawMosaicId);
        const amount = await userBalance(address, mosaicId);
        return [userId, amount, mosaicId]
    });

    const values = await Promise.allSettled(users);

    console.log("Chain over");
    for(let settled of values) {
        if (settled.status === "fulfilled")
        {
            const [user, amount, mosaicId] = settled.value;
            
            console.log(`User ${user}, amount of ${mosaicId.toHex()}: ${amount.toString()}`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Failed to get balance, reason: ${settled.reason}`);
        }
    }
    })();
}

async function userBalance(userAddress, mosaicId) {
    const repositoryFactory = new SymbolSdk.RepositoryFactoryHttp(nodeUrl);
    const accountHttp = repositoryFactory.createAccountRepository();
    let transactions = null;

    transactions = await accountHttp.getAccountInfo(userAddress)
        .toPromise();

    for (const mosaic of transactions.mosaics) {
        if (mosaicId.equals(mosaic.id)) {          
            return mosaic.amount;
        }
    }

    return new SymbolSdk.UInt64([0, 0]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.5/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

I think the cause was complex logic inside `Promise` callback and one can get lost

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem comes from the multiple creation of `accountHttp` object from the [repositoryFactory](https://nemtech.github.io/symbol-sdk-typescript-javascript/0.18.0/interfaces/_infrastructure_repositoryfactory_.repositoryfactory.html).

Moving these two lines up above the global scope so that they are executed only once seem to be fixing the issue.

```
const repositoryFactory = new SymbolSdk.RepositoryFactoryHttp(nodeUrl);
const accountHttp = repositoryFactory.createAccountRepository();
```